# how do I move a panel with directional keyboard

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

In a label docking on panel control I used this code:
(this is for move my panel with the mouse pointer)

```
Point m_pntPosPanel = new Point();

private void lblMove_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    pnlCost.Location = new Point(e.X - m_pntPosPanel.X + pnlCosto.Location.X, e.Y - m_pntPosPanel.Y + pnlCosto.Location.Y);
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    m_blnMouseDown = false;
}

private void lblMove_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        m_pntPosPanel.X = e.X;
        m_pntPosPanel.Y = e.Y;

        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Hand;
        m_blnMouseDown = true;
    }
}
```

how do I make to move that panel with `directional keyboard`?

Comment: Try with the event OnKeyDown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would register for the KeyUp event on the control and process as follows:

```
    private void lblMove_KeyUp(object server, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
          Point location = button1.Location;
          switch(e.KeyCode)
          {
            case Keys.Up: 
                location.Y = location.Y -1;
                break;
            case Keys.Down:
                location.Y = location.Y + 1;
                break;
            case Keys.Right:
                location.X = location.X + 1;
                break;
            case Keys.Left:
                location.X = location.X - 1;
                break;
          }

          button1.Location = location;
    }
```